# Problem with buffered File Reader

Tags: java

I have been asked to write a file reader method, I have done one which works fine but cant get the 2nd one to work and keep getting this error after i open the booms.txt file

> Error:java.util.NoSuchElementException

public instance variable

> public List booms;

Code I'm using for the file reader

> try
>
> ```
>     {
>         int x;
>         int y;
>         double boomTime;
>         boolean isAHit;
>         Scanner lineScanner;
>         bufferedFileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(aFile));
>         String currentLine = bufferedFileReader.readLine();
>         while (currentLine != null)
>         {
>             lineScanner = new Scanner(currentLine);
>             lineScanner.useDelimiter(",");
>             x = lineScanner.nextInt();
>             y = lineScanner.nextInt();
>             boomTime = lineScanner.nextDouble();
>             isAHit = lineScanner.nextBoolean();
>             booms.add(new Boom(x,y,boomTime));
>             currentLine = bufferedFileReader.readLine();
>         }
>     }
>     catch (Exception anException)
>     {
>         System.out.println("Error:"+anException);
>     }
>     finally
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             bufferedFileReader.close();
>         }
>         catch (Exception anException)
>         {
>             System.out.println("Error:" +anException);
>         }
>
> }
>
> }
> ```

Please Help

Comment: Why don't check stacktrace for details? _anException.printStackTrace();_

Comment: Do you know which exception the error is printing from?  Try changing your outputs to be different - make one "reading error:" and one "closing error:" for instance.  And then, like Nikita recommends, try printing the stack trace to see where the exception is being thrown from.

Comment: The NoSuchElementException is most probably thrown by the Scanner class. Like Maurice said, there may be a blank line in your file, so you're requesting a token by calling next*() when there is no input left.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a blank line at the end of the file?

Comment: Sorry you have lost me Maurice

Comment: The exception is thrown by the scanner. There must be a line in the file that does not conform to the expected syntax

Answer (score 0):

as maurice says, probably a blank or incorrect line of data in the file.

the exception (although you haven't posted the stack trace) is being thrown by the `Scanner.next...` calls.

[Scanner.nextInt](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29)

> NoSuchElementException - if input is
>   exhausted

this would be far more obvious to you and the members of this forum if you'd included the stack trace. try putting `anException.printStackTrace();` in your catch blocks next time.

Answer (score 0):

Got it sorted I had a boolean variable which wasn't in the file it was reading :), its all about taking a break and looking at it again.

Comment: mate, you don't post your own answers instead of accepting an answer. use the 'tick' next to one of the answers and add a comment if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a another method that's not that complicated. just do this:

```
Scanner diskScanner = new Scanner(new File("pathname"));
```

to read for example a Integer from the specified file just type

```
int blahblahblah = diskScanner.nextInt();
```